# SQLi Protection From User Input Text

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I usually put manual sqli parameter checks in place (i.e to check if input is a valid email).

Although in this case, I need to put a user message into my DB

How would this work?

I tried this code, but the whole input gets erased somehow.

```
<?php

$text = "Hello World";

echo "$text is now ";

$text = stripslashes($text);
$text = mysqli_real_escape_string($text);

echo $text;

?>
```

Thannk you!

Comment: `mysqli_real_escape_string` needs link parameter which is (Absent) over here and rest I can't understand what you really need to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To prevent SQL injection in PHP:**

You can achieve this using any of this way:

1. For [MySQLi](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (MySQL):

   ```
   $stmt = $dbConnection->prepare('SELECT id, username, email_id FROM users WHERE type = ?');
   $stmt->bind_param('s', $userType); // bind parameters
   $stmt->execute();

   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       // do something with $row
   }
   ```

   **Note:** For MySQLi use can use either Procedural style or [Object oriented style](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)(Recommended)
2. For [PDO](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (PDO is the universal solution for any supported database driver):

   ```
   $stmt = $this->db->prepare('SELECT id, username, email_id FROM users WHERE type =:user_type');
   $stmt->bindValue(':user_type', $userType);
   $stmt->execute();
   $user_list = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

   foreach ($user_list as $key => $list) {
       echo  '<a href="'.  $list['id'].'">' . $list['email_id']. '</a></br>';
   }
   ```

**PDO Connection**

```
try {
    $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', $user, $pass);
    foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from users') as $row) {
        print_r($row);
    }
    $dbh = null;
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

And For you the Linking parameter for `mysqli` like

```
$text = $db->mysqli_real_escape_string($text);
```

**Example:**

```
//Escaping characters
$db->real_escape_string('This is an unescaped "string"');
//There is an alias function that you can use which is shorter and less to type: 
$db->escape_string('This is an unescape "string"');
```